# what is the most elegant way to find the first column of a data.frame that has all unique values?

Tags: r, dataframe, key, unique

I have a data.frame which may contain any number of columns and values. I need to find the name of the first column (starting from lhs) that has all unique values.
e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(char = c("a", "b", "b"),
                 num = c(1.1, 2.2, 2.2),
                 key = c(1, 2, 3),
                 key2 = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

final solution should be: "key"

my solution:

```
  keys <- df[purrr::map_lgl(df, ~ !any(duplicated(.)))] 
  names(keys)[1]
```

works. I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this (efficient both in terms of processing time and amount of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for sure that there is at least one column with all unique values, then use:

```
which.min(sapply(df,anyDuplicated))
```

It will return

```
# key 
#   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` option is `Filter`

```
names(Filter(Negate(anyDuplicated), df))[1]
#[1] "key"
```